# Can I have more than one Contextual Class matched with one element?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have both Container class and Shadow class matched to my div (I put them in parentheses), However, it isn't working.

I know for classes, you could have `class = "Class 1 Class 2"`, but it seems like it isn't working for contextual class?

```
<div class="(container) p-3 my-3 border bg-dark rounded text-warning 
font-weight-bolder (shadow-lg) p-4 mb-4 bg-white">
     <h1 class="display-3">Container <small>small</small></h1> 
     <p class="spinner">Random</p>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this () brackets.

```html
no= (container)  yes=  container
no= (shadow-lg)  yes=  shadow-lg
```

Comment: I don't have the () brackets in my original code, I just put it here for visibility of classes. Sorry if that was misleading. Is the code suppose to work without the brackets? It didn't work for me :/